# fcm admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, messagePayload, options) is firing twice nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a NodeJs application that send notifications to multiple device platforms: Android and iOS. I am having a problem that when i call the sentToDevices(argToken, argPayload, argOptions) method,  it gets fired twice.

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(arrTokens, messagePayload, {dryRun: true})
  .then(devicesResponse => {
    console.log('Notifications send'); *// this code will print twice on the console*
  }).catch(error => {
     console.log('An error occurred while sending notification');
  })
```